# NHibernate + Spring.NET lazy loading failed - no session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, spring.net

I use Spring.NET AOP for transaction and session management with NHibernate. When user makes several requests too quick - lazy loading is failed with exception "no session or session was closed".

I use SpringSessionContext as CurrentSessionContext in NHibernate configuration

```
public class FluentSessionFactory : LocalSessionFactoryObject
{
    protected override ISessionFactory NewSessionFactory(Configuration config)
    {
        var conf = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration
                    .MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("MyConnection"))
                    // TODO: use ExposeConfiguration method
                    .CurrentSessionContext<SpringSessionContext>()
                )
            .Mappings(
                m => m.FluentMappings
                    .AddFromAssembly(this.GetType().Assembly)
            )
            .BuildSessionFactory();
        return conf;
    }
}
```

In xml config:

```
<object id="SessionFactory" type="IndustryTracker.NHibernateRepository.FluentSessionFactory, IndustryTracker.NHibernateRepository">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider" />
</object>
```

and OpenSessionInView module

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="OpenSessionInView"  type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate31"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Application implements next workflow for getting entities from db: View -> Controller -> Manager -> Repository and same to other side. So session is created per request, transaction - per call to manager.

```
<object id="TransactionManager" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate31">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
</object>

<tx:advice id="TxAdvice" transaction-manager="TransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<object id="Pointcut" type="Spring.Aop.Support.SdkRegularExpressionMethodPointcut, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="patterns">
        <list>
            <value>MyAppication.Managers.AccountManager</value>
            <value>MyAppication.Managers.CompanyManager</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</object>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="TxAdvice" pointcut-ref="Pointcut"/>
</aop:config>
```

What are possible reasons of such behaviour and how can I solve this problem(Not.LazyLoad() and NHibernateUtil.Initialize() are not acceptable variants in my context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. Session factory configured for `OpenSessionInViewModule`?*

You might have forgotten to configure the session factory for the `OpenSessionInViewModule`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" 
       value="SessionFactory"/>
</appSettings>
```

This has to be done in the app settings.

*2. Correct FluentNHibernate based spring session factory?*

You seem to be configuring your session factory in code. Have you tried configuring the [session factory like described in the docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#d4e6795) and on BennyM ['s blog](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2009/01/04/using-fluent-nhibernate-in-spring-net/)? Your `NewSessionFactory` method returns a session factory from straight from Fluent NHibernate, bypassing all spring.net support.

*3. Is your session factory transaction aware?*

```
<object id="SessionFactory" 
        type="IndustryTracker.NHibernateRepository.FluentSessionFactory, IndustryTracker.NHibernateRepository">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider" />
  <!-- provides integation with Spring's declarative transaction management features -->
  <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" /> 
</object>
```

*4. Does your controller have dependencies with `scope="application"` or no scope definition?*

I might have been looking in the wrong direction here. If your controller has dependencies of `application` scope, it would mean that quick requests could interfere. The default is `"scope="application"`; so you'd want to check collaborators without scope definitions too. See the docs on [web scopes](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.html#web-objectscope).

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't configured indeed. But fixing it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please post your session factory configuration too.

Comment: I've posted session factory configuration. As I understood - BennyM's post is for configuration of mappings. Can wrong mappings configuration be the reason?

Comment: I don't think mapping issues are the problem, because then you would get an exception on application startup. I think your session factory isn't correctly wired to spring.

Comment: I've set the property, described in your third update, but it also didn't help. About wiring to spring - it works great when doing request with normal speed, but crashes if make requests too quickly (for example multiple clicking on button).

Comment: I checked the spring source; `ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory` appears to be roughly equivalent to `.CurrentSessionContext<SpringSessionContext>` from your `FluentSessionFactory`; so in theory your `FluentSessionFactory` should work too.

Comment: And it works somehow, but on rapid clicking session isn't opend in second request. (First request creates and closes session, second doesn't create it).

Answer (score 2):

After some search I found that problem was in configuration. There was spring WebSupportModule missing http module in config, so the correct one is:

```
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
      <add name="OpenSessionInView" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule, Spring.Data.NHibernate31"/>  
    </httpModules>
```

So [Marijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322283/marijn)  was right - it was weak wiring to spring.